# Wordpress Plugin Function Rename

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

I have a problem where I have a function name conflict and I would like to know whether there is a way of renaming a function that is being used by a plugin so that there will be no conflicts.

The plugin I am using is S2 Member Pro and Accesspress Social Login. Both is using the wp_new_user_notification function.

Any guidance will be very much appreciated as I am not very familiar with modifying plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two plugins overriding the function wp_new_user_notification() on the same site. You could discuss with the plugin developers how important it is they override this function. In this situation I wouldn't go into the plugins and edit the contents as overriding this function might be integral to how they work. Have you checked the Wordpress support for both of these plugins to see if anyone else is coming up against this problem.